# energy computation for BVP with Dirichlet boundary conditions

Tags: optimization, finite-element, quadratic-programming

I am solving quadratic minimization problem
\begin{align}
\min_{x}\ \frac{1}{2} x^T A x -b^T x,
\end{align}

where matrix A results from discretization of Laplacian by FEM method, subjected to Dirichlet BC.

I am having concerns about computing energy. 
Should product $ \frac{1}{2} x^T A x -b^T x $ be computed by using matrix A with encoded modification for given BC (zero-ing off diagonals), or should it be done directly on unmodified (pure Neumann) matrix A ?

Is there any special treatment of boundary conditions needed ?

Comment: What is the unmodified matrix, what is the modified matrix?

Comment: If you have only homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions it would not matter. But in general, you should use your unmodified matrices to compute the energy.

Comment: @nicoguaro, why? (just curious)

Comment: @VorKir, they will be zeroes inside a summation.

Comment: @nicoguaro, will not they be like $d_{ii} x_i^2$ where $d_{ii}$ is the corresponding diagonal element of $A$ (which might be set to 1)?

Comment: @VorKir, I was talking about the degrees of freedom with homogenous Dirichlet boundary conditions.